# Vue.js b-table sub-component using built in filter: works but extremely sluggish

Tags: vue.js, filtering, bootstrap-vue

I have a vue page (Main.vue) which renders a component from a separate vue file (Table.Vue). When I had all the logic baked into Main.vue, the free-form text filter was working fine. But now it lags on almost every character I type in, so I'm thinking there may be something wrong with my implementation.

The code I've posted below has been simplified (ie removed pagination and computed stuff) to show what I'm stuck on.

Table.vue:

```
  <!-- search bar -->
  <b-input-group>
    <b-form-input v-model="filter" type="search" placeholder="Type to Search"></b-form-input>
    <b-input-group-append>
      <b-button :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">Clear</b-button>
    </b-input-group-append>
  </b-input-group>

  <b-table 
    :items="details" 
    :fields="fields" 
    :filter="filter"
    :current-page="currentPage"
    :per-page="perPage"
    @filtered="onFiltered"
  >
</b-container>
```

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'Table',
  props: ['details'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: 'ticket_number', sortable: true },
        { key: 'parent_id', label: 'Parent Ticket', sortable: true },
        { key: 'start', sortable: true, label: 'Start Date', formatter: (value) => { return moment(value, 'X').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A') }},
  ],
  // free text filter
  filter: null
  }
},
  computed: {
  rows: function(){
    return this.details.length
  }
},
created: function () {
  this.filteredDetails = this.details
},
methods: {
  onFiltered(filteredItems) {
    // Trigger pagination to update the number of buttons/pages due to filtering
    this.totalRows = filteredItems.length
    this.currentPage = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Main.vue:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="details !== null">
      <custtable :details="filteredDetails"/>
      <br/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { API } from '@/common/api.js'
import Table from '@/components/Table'

export default {
    name: 'Main',
    data: function() {
        return {
            details: [],
            filteredDetails: []
        }
    },
    components: {
        'custtable': Table
    }
}

</script>
```

So I'm wondering if the filter portion should even be in Table.vue: should it be in `Main.vue`? Where should the `filter` variable ideally be defined?

As stated, the functionality is there but it seems incredibly sluggish. The initial API call usually returns about 150 entries (JSON) so it's not a crazy amount of data.

I've been referencing [the docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#complete-example) up to this point.

Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has a unique ID field (i.e. a primary key), specify that field key name via the `primary-key` prop. This will optimize how Vue re-renders the table.

i.e. if your items array has a field `id` that is guaranteed to be unique across all rows of data, then set the prop `primary=key="id"`.

Filtering also needs to serialize each row's data into a single string of all the rows values, so it can take a bit of time if there are many fields (or deep nest fields).

Another option is to debouce your filter input.  Rather than passing the v-model of your filter input directly to b-table's `filter` prop, store it in an intermediate variable, and only update the copy of the input's value sent to b-table after so many milliseconds of no keypress (input events).

What is happening in your case is that the filter process is running across the entire table every character entered, which is re-triggering Vue to re-render the entire table. Using a combination of `primary-key` and input debouncing should improve performance for you.

Comment: Appreciate the informative answer Troy. I did set up the primary-key and that slightly helped with rendering, however still pretty slow. Looking at the Vue inspector under <Btable>, shouldn't it list the actual PK value instead of `ticket_number`? See here: https://i.imgur.com/QhjFvS1.png

Comment: The `primary-key` prop expects the **name** of the field, not the field value. It uses that name to lookup the value from the items row and assigns a Vue `:key` to the row that is based on the value looked up.  So each `<tr>` gets a unique Vue `:key` assigned, so Vue can optimize its rendering if the row data hasn't changed. It can also re-arrange DOM elements (i.e. when sorting or filtering) that are already rendered as long as the vNode key hasn't changed.

Comment: Ah that helps alot! When I just use the regular Inspect Element functionality now, I can see each <tr> has a `data-pk` attribute with the ticket_number there. Awesome!

Comment: And if you inspect the TR elements (the VM and it's vNode reference), you will also see there is a unique Vue key assigned, based on the rows primary key value.

Comment: We have just added a Pull Request that adds a new prop `filter-debounce`, which will let you specify a time in ms to debounce user input for the `filter` prop. It defaults to `0`, but you may find a value of 100ms may help. This feature will be available in the forthcoming 2.0.0 stable release.

Comment: Wow, awesome. Will give it a go! :)

Comment: Just wanted to check in and saw the PR for debouncing on form-input, works like a charm. Thank you for all that you do!

Comment: `<b-form-input>` now supports debouncing. Use it instead of `filter-debounce` (deprecated) on `<b-table>`

Comment: Yep that's what I was referring to, b-form-input. Working great!